# Issue configuring Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I've configured the plugin with scanning credentials.

Found branches with a Jenkinsfile.

However, I'm getting the error below and am not sure how to proceed.

```
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
[Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result
ERROR: Could not send notifications
com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.api.BitbucketRequestException: HTTP request error. Status: 400: Bad Request.
{"type": "error", "error": {"fields": {"url": ["Enter a valid URL."]}, "message": "Bad request"}}
```

Comment: Could you show your job configuration?